# Дан массив символов, содержащий текст. В строке между словами вставить вместо пробела запятую и пробел

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

void change(char *str);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");

    char str[100] = "The sun is hot.";  

    cout << str << endl;
    change(str);
    cout << str << endl;


    return 0;
}

void change(char *str){

    char chs[] = ", ";

    while (*str) {
        if (*str == ' ') {
            memcpy(str, chs, strlen(chs));
            str += strlen(chs);
        }
        else {
            str++;
        }           
    }
}
```

Помогите разобраться с задачей. Не понимаю как сдвинуть последующие элементы на одну позицию. У меня должна получится строка длиннее чем исходная.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так не пойдет. Вызывая memcpy, Вы же просто затираете следующий за обнаруженным пробелом байт (впрочем, Вы это и сами видите). Предполагая, что места в массиве после текста достаточно, нужно копировать (например, вызывая memove) весь хвост, т.е. сдвигать текст вправо вместе с пробелом, записывать запятую и пропустив сдвинутый вправо пробел, повторять поиск следующего пробела.

Comment: Тут же от C++ только cout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
void change(char *str)
{
    char chs[] = ", ";
    for(;*str;++str)
    {
        if (*str == ' ')
        {
            memmove(str+strlen(chs),str+1,strlen(str+1)+1);
            memmove(str,chs,strlen(chs));
            ++str;
        }
    }
}
```

`memmove` всегда корректно обрабатывает перекрывающиеся области.
Смещаем строку, расчищая место для вставляемой, и вставляем. Соответственно, сдвигаем указатель, а то опять пробел прочтем...

Минус вашего подхода - надо гарантировать, что в выделенном массиве хватит места для всех вставок.

Comment: спасибо, как я понял Вы в строке memmove(str+strlen(chs),str+1,strlen(str+1)+1);, грубо говоря увеличиваете длину строки, и что бы не было минуса нужно использовать динамический массив?

Comment: @Ilya Да. Можно просто пройти по строке, посчитать, сколько в ней пробелов, вычислить новую длину строки, выделить ее динамически и в цикле идти, копируя символы из одной строки во вторую, только перед пробелом вставляя запятую...

Answer (score 0):

В теге стоит C++, поэтому вот решение используя возможности оного:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void change(string &str);

int main()
{
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");

    string str = "The sun is hot.";

    cout << str << endl;
    change(str);
    cout << str << endl;


    return 0;
}

void change(string &str) 
{
    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
        if (str[i] == ' ') {
            str.insert(i, ",");
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/YLAYNa

Comment: Вы здесь работаете с указателем, как я понял ?

Comment: с неконстантной ссылкой: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ссылка_(C++). Тип строки: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string

Comment: Криво вставляется ссылка на Википедию: Ссылка_(C++)